# Node.js crypto gives webpack compile error

Tags: node.js, webpack, cryptography

I am developing an appilication using Node.js, react, yarn and webpack and I am not very experienced in these technologies.

I needed to use encryption and I tried to use the build-in Crypto module. The problem is that even with the simple command: `crypto = require('crypto');` in my js file, webpack compilation fails with the following messages:

```
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/parse-asn1/aesid.json
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (1:25)

> 1 | {"2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.1": "aes-128-ecb",
    |                          ^
  2 | "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2": "aes-128-cbc",
  3 | "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.3": "aes-128-ofb",
  4 | "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.4": "aes-128-cfb",
```

I have tried to use other encryption libraries like node-simple-encryptor and sjcl but I always get the same error!

I guess that it must be a webpack (version 3.5.2) problem, because when I use the same libraries in a test javascript file and run it from nodejs interactive environment, it runs OK.

Can anybody help me?

My webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
   entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'output'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/'
   },
   resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
             test: /\.js/,
             use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: { presets: ['react', 'es2015'] }
             }
         },
         {
            test: /\.scss/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
         }
      ]
   },
   devServer: {
     contentBase: './src',
     publicPath: '/output',
     historyApiFallback: true,
   },
   devtool: 'source-map' //Maps source files with bundle.js for debugging in the browser

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that babel / webpack are treating that JSON file as a js
try using this are the first module.rules test key
`test: /\.(js)$/,` instead of `test: /\.js/,`

Comment: Or just `/\.js$/` (or possibly `/\.jsx?$/` if they also use JSX files)

Comment: That was it, thank you very much! It worked with /\.(js)$/,